# When is this sequence of positive integers a square?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, square-numbers

> I have two sequences below, and I would like to know for which $n$ the number $k_n$ is a square.
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> k_1 &= 9\\
> t_1 &= 1\\
> k_{n+1} &= 9k_n + 80t_n\\
> t_{n+1} &= k_n + 9t_n
> \end{align}
> $$

I'm conjecturing that there are no $n>1$ such that $k_n$ is square based on computational evidence, however I'm having a hard time proving it. My main idea that I've been trying to use is induction, and saying that if $k_n$ is not a square, then $k_{n+1}$ is not a square. I've tried using modular arithemtic on the sequence with modulars such as $4$, $5$, $8$, $9$, $16$, $80$ and other obvious choices, however none of them avoided the quadratic residues in the cycle started from $k_2=161$.

If you can find an explicit formula for $k_n$, please do give it.

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}k_{n+1}\\t_{n+1}\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}9&80\\1&9\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}k_{n}\\t_{n}\end{array}\right)$$
and since the eigenvalues of the characteristic matrix are $9\pm 4\sqrt{5}$, we have:

> $$ k_n = \frac{1}{2}\left((2+\sqrt{5})^{2n} + (2-\sqrt{5})^{2n}\right),\tag{1} $$

with $k_{n+2}= 18 k_{n+1}-k_n$. It is interesting to notice that, by $(1)$,
$$ k_n = \frac{1}{2}\left((2+\sqrt{5})^n + (2-\sqrt{5})^n\right)^2-(-1)^n=\frac{1}{2}K_n^2-(-1)^n\tag{2}$$
so we can detect which elements of $\{k_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are squares by intersecting  the sequence $\{K_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with the two sequences giving the solutions of the Pell equations:
$$2A_n^2 \pm 1 = \square. $$

It is worth to try to adjust Cohn's proof of the fact that the only squares in the Fibonacci sequence are $0,1,144$. It can be found [here](https://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/SquareFibonacci.html).

Answer (score 0):

Automorph of $$ k^2 - 80 t^2. $$ By Cayley-Hamilton, both
$$  k_{n+2} = 18 k_{n+1} - k_n   $$ and
$$  t_{n+2} = 18 t_{n+1} - t_n   $$

So this is for that quartic you made up with the multiples of 10. Anyway, characteristic polynoial is $\lambda^2 - 18 \lambda + 1$ and the roots are irrational. That is the only thing available that gives a "formula" for $k_n.$ 
Let's see, $$ \lambda = \frac{18 \pm \sqrt {320}}{2} = \frac{18 \pm 8 \sqrt {5}}{2} = 9 \pm 4 \sqrt 5 = 9 \pm  \sqrt {80}.    $$ Both are positive, so
there are real constants $A,B$ such that
$$  k_n = A \left(9 +  \sqrt {80} \right)^n + B \left(9 -  \sqrt {80} \right)^n. $$

Comment: Okay I guess I asked for a formula for $k_n$, so this partially answers the question, the thing I'm really looking for is when $k_n$ is square.

Comment: @KristofferRyhl, suggest you buy or borrow Diophantine Equations by Mordell. Chapter 4 is on quartic equations with only trivial solutions.

Comment: It is quite crucial to notice that $9\pm 4\sqrt{5}=(2\pm\sqrt{5})^2$ and $A=B=\frac{1}{2}$, so the squares in the sequence can be found by Kedlaya's method.

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, suggest you give more detail on Kedlaya in your answer, I don't know it.

Comment: @WillJagy: it is a general method for detecting the intersections of two Fibonacci-like sequences with a characteristic polynomial of degree two, I just have to find the original Kedlaya's notes.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, understood.